# 'Moving' unchanging char array into const std::string

Tags: c++, string, performance, c++11, stdstring

I've identified the bottleneck in my program as the copy operation from intaking a w_char[] and initializing a string from it, thus copying the buffer.

```
const std::wstring name = payload->Header->Name;
```

This code happens over and over again with different values, but for the lifetime of `name`, the payload struct cannot change. So there is only need for a single buffer to exist. The wchar array comes from an API that cannot change. And there is subsequent code that expects `name` to be a wstring and is well optimized already and I consider it cleaner that it uses wstring and not arrays.

I know under the hood, wstring is just a wchar buffer anyway. What I need is like the general equivalent of std::move but for this special case. Is there no standard way to even signify the *intent* here, so the compiler could maybe optimize this if it can?

Comment: The "subsequent code" would need to be changed to take a `string_view` (C++17 proposal) or something equivalent

Comment: was "intaking a char[]` meant to read "intaking a `wchar_t[]`" ? otherwise you really do need 2 buffers.

Comment: If boost is allowed use boost::string_ref ( http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/utility/doc/html/string_ref.html)